# How to write if/else statement in swift so that when a specific cell is clicked in iOS tableview it goes to a specific viewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableView with multiple cells that go to a single viewController. I'm setting up a new viewController for a specific cell that, when selected, will open its own viewController for that specific cell. How do I add another if/else statements for a second cell when selected to go to its own ViewController which will be the third VC? How do I implement this correctly in Swift?

I already have one if/else statement that when the cell in section"0" row "0" is selected to go to the reciprocity view controller.  It works fine, however, how do I add another statement for a cell at section "0" row "20" to go to its own viewController.  I am a newbie in swift and trying to learn correctly. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
`override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt   indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if ((indexPath.section == 0) && (indexPath.row == 0)) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "reciprocityView", sender: nil);
    if ((indexPath.section == 0) && (indexPath.row == 20)) {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "InterestViewController", sender: nil)
        }
    } else {
        let productLine = productLines[indexPath.section]
        let product = productLine.products[indexPath.row]
        selectedProduct = product
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showProductDetail", sender: nil)}
}
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if segue.identifier == "showProductDetail" {
            let DetailVC = segue.destination as!     DetailViewController
            DetailVC.product = selectedProduct
        }

        }
    }`
```

Since I added the ((indexPath.section == 0) && (indexPath.row == 20, that cell continues to go to the default viewController instead of the InterestViewController.

Comment: Fix your indenting and you will see your problem; you second `if` is inside your first `if`. The second `if` should be an `else if`

Comment: Can you show me an example.  I am self taught and is still learning swift.  Sorry  I am learning how to use the if/else statement.  Showing me an example, I can learn the correct syntax.  Also can you show me what you mean by fixing the indenting.  I thought it was correct, but I must be wrong

Comment: @blaw I’ve suggested an edit to your post. It simply adjusts the formatting a bit. It should help you see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second if statement never fires, because you are calling it from inside the first if statement. Cell row can not be 0 and 20 at the same time. You need an else if statement outside that.

```
if condition {
   do something
} else if condition2 {
   do something else
} else {
   do something else
}
```

Comment: Wow, I see now, Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if(indexPath.section == 0)
            {
                newworkrequest()
            }else if(indexPath.section == 1)
            {
                requestlist()
            }
}

@objc func newworkrequest()
{
    let viewcontroller : new_work_request = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newworkRequest") as! new_work_request
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller, animated: true)
    }
    @objc func requestlist()
    {
        let viewcontroller : workrequestlist = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "requestlist") as! workrequestlist
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller, animated: true)
    }
```